# How is CSS linked to <head>

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I want to edit these css links but I can't find them in my header.php (they are supposed to be there), where do they come from?

```
rel='stylesheet' id='js_composer_front-css'  href='//metasyfe.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/js_composer.css' type='text/css' media='all' /><link
rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css'  href='//metasyfe.com/wp-content/themes/startuply/css/lib/bootstrap.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' /><link
rel='stylesheet' id='startuply_custom-css'  href='//metasyfe.com/wp-content/themes/startuply/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' /><link
rel='stylesheet' id='startuply_ptsans-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans%3A400%2C700%2C400italic%2C700italic&#038;subset=latin%2Ccyrillic-ext%2Clatin-ext%2Ccyrillic' type='text/css' media='all' /><link
rel='stylesheet' id='startuply_lato-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato%3A100%2C300%2C400%2C700%2C900%2C100italic%2C300italic%2C400italic%2C700italic%2C900italic' type='text/css' media='all' /><link
rel='stylesheet' id='vsc-animation-style-css'  href='//metasyfe.com/wp-content/themes/startuply/engine/extend/animations/css/vivaco-animations.css' type='text/css' media='all' /><script type='text/javascript' src='//metasyfe.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js' defer='defer'></script><script type='text/javascript' src='//metasyfe.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js' defer='defer'></script><script type='text/javascript' src='//metasyfe.com/wp-content/themes/startuply/engine/extend/animations/js/vivaco-animations.js' defer='defer'></script><link
rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="//metasyfe.com/xmlrpc.php?rsd" /><link
rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="//metasyfe.com/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /><meta
name="generator" content="WordPress 4.3.1" /><link
```

Comment: Check for a sitewide style sheet getting added from outside your project.  Also look for other server-side includes that may be adding this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress uses `wp_enqueue_style` and `wp_enqueue_script` to add your CSS/JS files to your header.

Some of the files your mentioned come from plugins while others come from your `wp-content/themes/startuply/functions.php` file.

**UPDATE**

This is an example of how you can enqueue **JS** to your `header`:

```
wp_register_script('script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scriptname.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true); // Custom scripts
wp_enqueue_script('script'); // Enqueue it!
```

And this is to enqueue **CSS**:

```
wp_register_style('normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/normalize.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
wp_enqueue_style('normalize'); // Enqueue it!
```

You can read more here

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: You are on point man, thanks!  I thought that enqueue just prepped the files so they don't duplicate.

Comment: Yes `wp_enqueue_*` adds the CSS/JS to the queue while `wp_register_*` prepares it to be added

Comment: Is there any other place where styles are loaded? There's one style that I can't find in the functions.php

Comment: Which stylesheet are you referring to?

Comment: I meant which stylesheet are you looking for from the ones you posted in your question?

Comment: wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/lib/typicons/src/font/typicons.min.css

/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/lib/vc-entypo/vc_entypo.css

wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/lib/vc-open-iconic/vc_openiconic.css'

Comment: You'll have to search all the files contained in the `http://metasyfe.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer` folder for those files. No way of telling you where they are enqueued from without actual plugin files.